# I am trying to load Local XML file using locally run JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

When I run this code to load up my external, locally stored XML file to run on the locally ran JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", "data.xml", true)
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    var xmlDocument = xhr.responseXML
    console.log("xml loaded")
  } else {
    console.log("readystate = " + xhr.readyState)
    console.log("status = " + xhr.status)
  }
}
xhr.send()
```

I *believe* this code should have the whole XML file (data.xml) loaded in as the variable "xmlDocument" by the end. This should all work fine if I wasn't getting this as the status:
[variable "readystate" changes from 3 to 4 while status stays at 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZez3.jpg)

I have a feeling that this is simply because it is all local.
I do not need this to be run on any server, all this will ever need to be is ran locally.

I have not tried running this on a GitHub pages server as that would be the only resource I have available, for legal reasons... Sort of the same reason this will ever only need to be run locally. I have tried renaming, using different folder hierarchies etc.

Comment: You cannot use neither `XMLHttpRequest` nor `Fetch` APIs "locally" for security reasons. You want to look at `File` API instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads) with [LiveServer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) to run a "web server" locally. Then this would work:

```js
try {
   const text = await fetch('data.xml');
   const xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString( text, "text/xml" );

   // do something with xml

} catch( error ){
   console.error( error );
}
```